# Yii Active Record for MS SQL Server via Odbc without access to INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Tags: php, sql-server, activerecord, yii, odbc

I'm trying to use Yii Active Record for MS SQL Server connected via ODBC. It works as long as user have an access to INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Is it possible to use Active Record without access to INFORMATION_SCHEMA?

Comment: No... the ActiveRecord build the related sql function based on INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Comment: thank you is all what I need to know

Answer (score 0):

You can cache schema to avoid additional requests for every query.
You can modify your config file like this:

```
'db' => array(
   // db connection params

   'schemaCacheID' => 'cache', // cacheing component name
   'schemaCachingDuration' => '3600' // cache keeping duration in seconds
)
```

Be sure that you "turned on" [cache](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.overview) component:

```
'cache'=>array(
    'class'=>'system.caching.CFileCache'
),
```